# Canvas not visible on particular device (One X)

Tags: java, android

I think I am facing a small issue. My problem is that I am drawing a speedometer based on  http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/. And the needle is visible on all devices that I have but not on HTC One X. On checking, I found that the canvas density (canvas.getDensity()) is returned as 0. Could that be the reason it is not visible? Also tested on S3 which has the same OS (4.0.4). Works fine there.

```
    handPath = new Path();
    handPath.moveTo(0.5f, 0.5f + 0.0f);
    handPath.lineTo(0.5f - 0.010f, 0.5f + 0.0f - 0.00f);
    handPath.lineTo(0.5f - 0.002f, 0.5f - 0.22f);
    handPath.lineTo(0.5f + 0.002f, 0.5f - 0.22f);
    handPath.lineTo(0.5f + 0.010f, 0.5f + 0.0f - 0.00f);
    handPath.lineTo(0.5f, 0.5f + 0.0f);
    handPath.addCircle(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.05f, Path.Direction.CW);


    private void drawHand(Canvas canvas) {
    // if (handInitialized) {
    float handAngle = degreeToAngle(handPosition);
    // float handAngle = 0;
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.rotate(handAngle, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    canvas.drawPath(handPath, handPaint);
    canvas.restore();
    float scale = getScaled(canvas,canvas.getWidth());
    canvas.scale(scale, scale);
    canvas.drawCircle(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.01f, handScrewPaint);
    // }
}
```

Comment: android 4.0.4 on one device is not necessarily the same as android 4.0.4 on another one. An annoying fact when it comes to android.

Comment: Could the issue be with the density being returned as 0?

Comment: it could be, where are you calling `getDensity()`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this person got the solution for this or not. But, the below answer is for the people who are still searching for the solution for this. Please add the below lines in the init function

`@TargetApi(11)
    private void init() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
         }
       ........
       ........
       ........
    }`

I hope this solves the needle display problem